# Redis - Pyredis iterating through results from SINTER on SET

Tags: python, redis

I have 2 SET structures with the following values added:

```
r.sadd("clONE", 'abc')
r.sadd("clONE", 'def')
r.sadd("clONE", 'ghi')

r.sadd("TWO", 'abc')
r.sadd("TWO", 'def')

print(r.sinter("clONE", "TWO"))
 OUTPUT: set(['abc', 'def'])
```

How do I get the value 'abc' and the 'def' out of the SET() using pyredis? I tried using array syntax by specifying array index[0] but got the following error

```
print(r.sinter("clONE", "TWO")[0])

TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sets are not indexed. The order depends on the internal hash.
Never rely on the order in a set, even if it appears logical.

You can do the following:

```
s = r.sinter("clONE", "TWO")

# iterate through the set, unsorted
for i in s:
    print(i)
```

or

```
l = sorted(s)  # returns a sorted list (alphanum)
print(l[0])  # will print 'abc'
```